# Race-condition with web workers when setting onmessage handler?

Tags: html, race-condition, web-worker

Please consider the following code and the explanation from this Mozilla tutorial ["Using web workers"](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Using_web_workers#Spawning_a_worker):

```
var myWorker = new Worker('my_worker.js');
myWorker.onmessage = function(event) {
  print("Called back by the worker!\n");
};
```

> Line 1 in this example **creates and
>   starts running the worker thread.** 
>   Line 2 sets the onmessage handler for
>   the worker to a function that is
>   called when the worker calls its own
>   postMessage() function.

The thread is started in the moment the *Worker* constructor is called. I wonder if there might be a race-condition on setting the *onmessage* handler. For example if the web worker posts a message before *onmessage* is set.

Does someone know more about this?

**Update:**

Andrey pointed out that the web worker should start its work, when it receives a message, like in the  Fibonacci example in the Mozilla tutorial. But doesn't that create a new race-condition on setting the onmessage handler in the web worker?

For example:

The main script:

```
var myWorker = new Worker('worker.js');
myWorker.onmessage = function(evt) {..};
myWorker.postMessage('start');
```

The web worker script ('worker.js')

```
var result = [];
onmessage = function(evt) {..};
```

And then consider the following execution path:

```
main thread                                  web worker
var worker = new Worker("worker.js");
                                             var result = [];
myWorker.onmessage = ..
myWorker.postMessage('start');
                                             onmessage = ..
```

The "*var result = []*" line can be left out, it will still be the same effect.

And this is a valid execution path, I tried it out by setting a timeout in the web worker! At the moment I can not see, how to use web workers without running into race-conditions?!

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34409254/are-messages-sent-via-worker-postmessage-queued

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is that both the main script and the web worker have a *MessagePort* queue which collects the messages before the *initial worker script returns*.

For details, see this thread on the WHATWG help mailing list:
https://web.archive.org/web/20140401202427/http://lists.whatwg.org/pipermail/help-whatwg.org/2010-August/000606.html

Comment: The link to the mailing list is now broken. Any idea where to read the thread, or alternately, were there any gotchas?

Comment: @HRJ Sorry, I can't find an archived version of the thread. But there are no gotchas, a message queue makes sure that you don't have to worry about race conditions.

Comment: https://web.archive.org/web/20140401202427/http://lists.whatwg.org/pipermail/help-whatwg.org/2010-August/000606.html

Comment: I think this comment from a deleted answer is important: "The message simply goes into paren't window's message queue, since the parent window is still executing Javascript." This is not what programmers in multithreaded environments are used to. If I understand that correctly, JS pretends web worker creating creating and settings its onmessage in the same script are atomic - the onmessage will not be called until the current script finishes.