# are messages sent via worker.postMessage() queued?

Tags: web-worker

After creating a worker, I can send messages to it via `postMessage`. For example:

```
var worker = new Worker('helper.js');
worker.postMessage({...});
```

Inside helper.js, the worker needs to add a listener using `onmessage = function (event) { ... };`

My question is, if one or more messages are sent to the worker while the worker script is still loading, is it guaranteed that the messages get queued and delivered eventually, or is it possible that they may get lost?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The spec at http://www.w3.org/TR/2015/WD-workers-20150924/#communicating-with-a-dedicated-worker says

> The implicit MessagePort used by dedicated workers has its port message queue implicitly enabled when it is created

Also

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Worker/postMessage doesn't mention having to wait for the worker to load before sending messages
- Testing posting messages immediately after creating a worker that can't be in the cache http://plnkr.co/edit/jM1qy9lDEFKYhR0TDsKa?p=preview

  ```
  var worker = new Worker('worker.js?' + (new Date()).getTime());
  worker.postMessage('');
  worker.postMessage('');
  ```

  with the worker just outputting to the console

  ```
  self.onmessage = function() {
    console.log('received');
  }
  ```

  has always shown 2 console messages for me when testing. This isn't a guarantee that it will always work this way though, but given that I'm trying to make it lose messages and failing, it is reasonable evidence.

Comment: The latest version of the spec says "The implicit MessagePort used by dedicated workers has its port message queue implicitly enabled when it is created, so there is no equivalent to the MessagePort interface's start() method on the Worker interface". That implies that what "The implicit MessagePort ... has its port message queue implicitly enabled" really means is that `start()` has been called on the MessagePort, which "starts the sending of messages queued on the port".  That would explain why messages can get lost in the example from tobek's answer.

Answer (score 12):

Messages will be queued while the worker script is being downloaded and parsed by the browser, but **`onmessage` must be defined synchronously in the worker** (at least in Chrome v56).

The following will *not* fully work:

worker.js:

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  onmessage = function() {
    console.log('received message');
  }
}, 0);
```

main-script.js:

```js
var worker = new Worker('worker.js');
worker.postMessage('first message'); // this won't go through
setTimeout(function() {
  worker.postMessage('second message'); // this will
}, 1000);
```

The worker's `onmessage` function will only fire for the second message.

I've demonstrated this issue in this plunkr: http://embed.plnkr.co/G54gk9Cz6XhZ3E6ZB3Nf/

`importScripts` *does* stop execution in the worker until the scripts are downloaded, so waiting until after that to define `onmessage` should be fine.