# How to know if a web worker instance process finished

Tags: web-worker

All:

I am pretty new to JS Web Worker, say when I instantiate a web work like:

```
var worker = new Worker("worker.js");
```

and then I call:

```
worker.postMessage("Start working");
```

There is one question confused me:

How do I know if the worker is ready for my postMessage call( I thought new Worker need some time to finish, **will there be some problems if I call postMessage too fast that the worker is not even ready, especially there are some asyn operation inside worker.js**)?  Or I do not need to worry about this, cos this operation is synchronous, **I can assume the worker is ready(if no problem with worker.js) when I call postMessage**?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [are messages sent via worker.postMessage() queued?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34409254/are-messages-sent-via-worker-postmessage-queued)

Answer (score 1):

The act of creating a new worker via `new Worker(...)` is synchronous, so when your next line runs it is ready for `postMessage(...)`.

Check out the HTML5Rocks' [The Basics of Web Workers](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/workers/basics/) for the nitty gritty.

Comment: thanks, I guess my main problem is what if there is some async operation inside the initialization of Worker?

Comment: @Kuan That's something you have to manage yourself.  If your worker cannot effectively handle a call to `postMessage()` immediately, you'll have to come up with some scheme to queue up the message yourself for when the async operation the Worker is doing completes.

Comment: "The act of creating a new worker via new Worker(...) is synchronous"

Note that this is not entirely true; if you have a blocking code after `new Worker(...)`, you will notice that a new thread is not created until that code (and entire current event loop tick) has finished executing.

So, if you care about a new worker being created *before* you run that code, you need to wait for the next tick.

In all other situations, yes, you can use `.postMessage` which will queue messages automatically for when a worker is ready.