# Worker.onmessage firing synchronously?

Tags: javascript, race-condition, web-worker

Investigating a strange bug for which the stack trace (on Firefox 87) points to the line where the `onmesssage` handler is assigned:

```js
const worker = new Worker(/* URI */);
worker.onmessage = msg => { // stacktrace points here
    let trx = JSON.parse(msg.data);
    // ...
}
// more init code
```

The calls in the stacktrace leading into this spot match the context in which the worker is created and `onmessage` assigned, but the calls after this spot in the stack trace make it seem like the handler function is called synchronously when assigned.

The worker itself connects to the server and can push messages to the main thread, without the main thread first having to post messages to it. It's thus entirely possible for a new message to be there before the `onmessage` assignment is executed. However, I've been unable to reproduce the behavior. It seems messages posted before the handler is assigned are discarded.

Short of a race condition in Firefox itself, is there anything else that could be going on?

(The race in question here is different from [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3213433/race-condition-with-web-workers-when-setting-onmessage-handler))

Comment: The stack could be a Dev-tools only weird thing. To be sure, try to execute something right after the `onmessage`.  Per specs, the whole Worker script should get executed before the Worker's channel (which comes from the main thread) get entangled in the worker's own channel. So any message posted before the worker's script ends, will get queued and executed at least in the Worker's next event loop iteration.

Comment: The stacktrace was actually collected via Sentry, so don't think it'd be a devtools thing. (Though maybe the user had dev tools open I guess...)

Comment: My point is that you should probably not read too much from the stack-trace regarding the a/synchronicity of what happened. Test directly.

Comment: Well, the bug report itself is proof of the synchronicity. The `onmessage` handler was called before the `// more init code` was run